# Setup delay for pod shutdown on update

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to setup a delay for pod shutdowns after a rolling update on Kubernetes?

For example I roll out a new version and want the old Pods to run for further 15secs after the new instance has been started.

How can I manage that?

Comment: I have update my answer to include a link for example on how to set `PreStop` hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `PreStop` Hook to achieve that.

`PreStop` hooks are executed after a Pod is marked as terminating. See what happen when you delete a pod from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods).

You just have to run `sleep 15` on `PreStop` Hook.

For more details see [Container hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks).

See how to add a `PreStop` hook from here: [Define postStart and preStop handlers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#define-poststart-and-prestop-handlers).